# IP Restricting admin pages with whitelist in custom module

Tags: hooks

This needs to be done within Drupal as my architecture does not allow for htaccess restriction.

I'm coming over from wordpress here so I've sort've Frankensteined this together from my wordpress code. Any thoughts or help on why this wouldn't be working?

Or maybe there is a much better way of doing this in code somewhere else? Or with some other function?

I'm on drupal 7.

```
function hook_init() {
if (path_is_admin(current_path()))
{
    // Whitelist
    $whitelist = array(
        'SOME IP ADDRESS',
    );

    // Check if current user IP is out of the whitelist, then redirect to home
    if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist))
    {
        drupal_goto('frontpage', 302);
        drupal_exit();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not.need to be done in code. I.would use https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip  and set a role for specific IP that would have the specific  permissions that you need.